# How to make a linux pc go to sleep after a period of time?

Tags: linux, archlinux, kde-plasma

I'm running an Arch Linux KDE PC, and I like to listen to calming music before sleeping.

What command/script that I can run on my PC to make the device go to sleep (Or shutdown) after a period of time?

Example: `Shutdown in 1.5h` OR `Sleep in 1.5h`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To shutdown, use the relative format (+m) and schedule a shutdown in a defined number of minutes from the time you run the command. The command syntax is:

```
sudo shutdown +m
```

For example, to shut down the system in 90 minutes, run:

```
sudo shutdown +90
```

To suspend the system after 90 minutes, run:

```
sleep 90m && systemctl suspend
```

Similar workaround for powering off the system after 90 minutes is to run:

```
sleep 90m && systemctl poweroff
```

Comment: I see, so the shutdown command takes minutes as default which means in my case I would run `sudo shutdown +90`

How about the sleep? If I don't want to completely turn off my device but have the screen turned off or have it go to sleep, how will I go about doing that?

Comment: You could use `sleep 90m && systemctl suspend` .

Comment: Perfect, this one did the trick, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote the answer